# Group Theoretical Classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\textbf{Definitions}$

Let $\mathfrak X$ be a class of groups (such as the one of cyclic groups).

Let $\textbf H\mathfrak X$ be the class of factor groups of $\mathfrak X$-groups.

Let $\textbf R\mathfrak X$ be the class of groups $G$ such that we can find normal subgroups, whose intersection is trivial, and such that their factor groups are $\mathfrak X$-groups. The elements of $\textbf R\mathfrak X$ will be called $\textbf{residually}\, \mathfrak{X}\textbf{-groups}$.

$\textbf{Problem}$

Let $\mathfrak X$ be a class of groups.

I want to show that $\textbf{R(H}\mathfrak X\textbf )\subset \textbf{H(R}\mathfrak X\textbf )$

$\textbf{Tries}$

Substantially a group $G$ in the first class is a group with normal subgroups, with trivial intersection, and relative factor group a $\textbf H\mathfrak X$-group (a factor group of a $\mathfrak X$-group). So we have to show that $G$ is a factor group of a residually $\mathfrak X$-group.

Since $G$ has normal subgroup with a trivial intersection we can embedd it in the cartesian product of the quotient of that normal subgroup. Now, each quotient is isomorphic to a factor group of a $\mathfrak X$-group (say $L_i$). Now the cartesian product of the $L_i$ is a $\textbf R\mathfrak X$-group and $G$ is embedded in a quotient of a residually $\mathfrak X$-group.

This is what I worked out.

Help, I need somebody, help! (xD)

$\textbf{Note}$: This is a "straight forward" demonstration of "Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups",  D.J.S. Robinson (page 6, Lemma 1.12).

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct definition of residually $X$-groups? The usual one says that $G$ is residually $X$ iff the intersection of all normal subgroups whose quotient groups (you call them factor groups) are $X$ is trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure your definition of "residually $\;\mathfrak X\;$ groups is accurate: a group $\;G\;$ is R$\mathfrak X\;$ iff $\;\forall\,1\neq g\in G\;\;\exists\;$ a normal $\;\mathfrak X\;$ subgroup $\;N\;$  s.t. $\;g\neq N\;$, which is the same as requiring that the intersection of all the normal $\;\mathfrak X\;$ subgroups of $\;G\;$ is trivial. Not only "there are some normal subgroups..."

Comment: Rats! MArtin wrote almost the same as I did...but shorter.

Comment: Aren't we saying the same thing?

"Let $\textbf R\mathfrak X$ be the class of groups $G$ such that we can find some normal subgroups, whose intersection is trivial, and such that their factor groups are $\mathfrak X$-groups. The elements of $\textbf R\mathfrak X$ will be called $\textbf{residually}\, \mathfrak{X}\textbf{-groups}$."

I mean that $G$ has normal subgroups $N_\lambda,\, \lambda \in \Lambda$ such that $G/N_\lambda \in \mathfrak X$ and the intersection of the $N_\lambda$ is trivial. Are not equivalent definitions?

Comment: "G is residually X iff the intersection of all normal subgroups whose quotient groups (you call them factor groups) are X is trivial." Then we have some normal subgroups with the property I mean. Au contraire if there are some subgroups with the definition I intend then a fortiori the intersection of all normal subgroups  whose quotient groups are $\mathfrak X$ is trivial. Analougsly as concern DonAntonio. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah ok, the definitions are equivalent. I thought that you restrict to two or finitely many normal subgroups (by reading "*some* normal subgroups"). Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, yes: it was written "some normal subgroups"....now it is not.

Comment: @W4cc0, if you add "some" to "normal subgroups" then you can *always* choose the trivial group...

Comment: Sorry about my misuse of the word "some" (and probably others xD). I edited the question.

Comment: @DonAntonio: No, the quotient is the group itsself and should be in $X$ then.

Comment: Not according to the definition the OP gave, @MartinBrandenburg: he states the subgroups (the "some normal...etc") must have quotients in $\;\mathfrak X\;$, and the trivial subgroup indeed has...

Comment: @DonAntonio: To be clear that we are talking about the same definition: $G \in \textbf{R}(\mathfrak{X})$ iff there is a family of normal subgroups $N_i$ such that $\cap_i N_i = \{1\}$ and $G/N_i \in \mathfrak{X}$ for all $i$. Thus, we can take $N_i=\{1\}$ (for some $i$) iff $G \in \mathfrak{X}$.

Comment: That *I know* , @Martin : it's the usual definition of residual $\mathfrak X\;$ , **not** what the OP wrote.

Comment: What do you think that the OP wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\mathfrak{X}$ is closed under subgroups. Then $G \in \textbf{R}(\mathfrak{X})$ iff $G$ embeds into a product of groups in $\mathfrak{X}$.

Let $G \in \textbf{R}(\textbf{H}(\mathfrak{X}))$, hence there is an embedding $G \hookrightarrow \prod_i G_i/N_i$ with $G_i \in \mathfrak{X}$ and $G \to G_i/N_i$ is surjective. Let $P = \prod_i G_i$ and $N = \prod_i N_i$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\prod_i G_i/N_i \cong P/N$, hence isomorphic to $H/N$ for some subgroup $N \leq H \leq P$. We see $H \in \textbf{R}(\mathfrak{X})$ and hence $G \in \textbf{H}(\textbf{R}(\mathfrak{X}))$.

Comment: Why $H\in \textbf R (\mathfrak X)$? Maybe $\mathfrak X$ is not subgroup closed...

Comment: Please read the first line of my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't really see why if $G$ embeds into a product of groups in $\mathfrak X$ then $G\in \textbf R (\mathfrak X)$. I think that if $\mathfrak X$ is not subgroup closed the only thing that we can say is the following: $G\in  \textbf R (\mathfrak X)$ iff $G$ embeds into a product of groups in $\mathfrak X$ and the projections of $G$ on each component are surjective. I have difficult on this point, if you could please give me some more details about this I will be satisfied.

Comment: Yeah, probably one has to assume that $\mathfrak{X}$ is closed under subgroups. This is satisfied in the typical applications.

Comment: Anyway I think that in your answer $H$ has surjective projections (also when $\mathfrak X$ is not subgroup closed); so I think it's fine.